# How to add swipelayout in recyclerview inside viewpager fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, swipeview

I'm using [AndroidSwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) for 'Swipe To Delete' Action in RecyclerView Item. Swipe is not working as parent of RecyclerView is ViewPager Fragment. SwipeLayout also contain parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); to intercept touchEvent from parent. What is the solution for this without disabling ViewPager swipe.

Comment: [Swipes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.swipesapp.android) todo app contain same Swipe Action inside ViewPager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `setOnTouchListener` for your list row within your adapter like below:

```
yourListRowContent.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    yourViewPager.setPagerEnabled(false);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

By using `yourViewPager.setPagerEnabled(false);` it will dissable your viewpager when you swipe your list content but again do like below in your Fragment (this will re activate your viewpager) :

```
yourRecyclerViewInFragment.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            HomeFragment.mPager.setPagerEnabled(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I prefer this `yourListRowContent.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    yourViewPager.setPagerEnabled(false);
                }else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
yourViewPager.setPagerEnabled(true);
}
                return true;
            }
        });`